# Transforming NetCDF file in longlat projection into TIF in EASE 2.0 using gdal_translate and gdalwarp

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, netcdf, gdal-translate

My goal is to convert 1 subband from .nc files (which I have several thousand if it matters) stored in longlat projection into .tif files in EASE 2.0 projection.

I do that in 2 steps:

**1. gdal_translate from .nc to .tif like so:**

```
for file in *.nc
do
gdal_translate -of GTiff NETCDF:"$file":vod   ${file%.*}.tif
done
```

At this stage I get a warning:

```
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
```

which I have no idea what to do about (I Googled and similar warnings seem to come from not specifying the sub band, but I do that - :vod). Also, these .nc files seem to have this warning initially in the info (see below).

**2. reproject .tif to EASE 2.0, which is [EPSG:6933](https://epsg.org/crs_6933/WGS-84-NSIDC-EASE-Grid-2-0-Global.html), which is not defined in gdal implicitly, so I use the projection parameters from the EPSG website**

```
for file in *.tif
do 
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +to wgs84=0,0,0" -t_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" -srcnodata -32768 -r bilinear "$file" "tr$file"
done
```

which seems to go smoothly.

Only when I try to open the resulting .tif in python I get the following error:

```
from PIL import Image

m = Image.open('myfile.tif')
```

```
IOError: cannot identify image file 'myfile.tif'
```

So, my **questions** are:

**1. Is the warning in step 1 the source of the problem?**

**2. Is the problem with python not opening the file has nothing to do with reprojections?**

Some additional info from gdalinfo:

**Initial file**

```
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: vodca_v01-0_C-band_2018-12-29.nc
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#_NCProperties=version=1|netcdflibversion=4.4.1.1|hdf5libversion=1.10.2
  NC_GLOBAL#band=C-band (6.8 GHz - 7.3 GHZ)
  NC_GLOBAL#calendar=standard
  NC_GLOBAL#contact=vodca@geo.tuwien.ac.at
  NC_GLOBAL#conventions=CF-1.6
  NC_GLOBAL#creatorname=Department of Geodesy and Geoinformation, Technical University of Vienna
  NC_GLOBAL#creatorurl=http://rs.geo.tuwien.ac.at
  NC_GLOBAL#DOI=10.5281/zenodo.2575599
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatmax=90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatmin=-90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatresolution=0.25 degree
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatunits=degrees_north
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonmax=180.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonmin=-180.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonresolution=0.25 degree
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonunits=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatialverticalmax=0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatialverticalmin=0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#insitute=Technical University of Vienna (AUT); Transmissivity B.V. / VanderSat B.V. Noordwijk (NL)
  NC_GLOBAL#license=Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International
  NC_GLOBAL#namingauthority=TU Wien
  NC_GLOBAL#product_version=01.0
  NC_GLOBAL#productname:=VODCA
  NC_GLOBAL#sensors=SSMI, TMI, AMSR-E, WindSat, AMSR2
  NC_GLOBAL#spatialresolution=25 km
  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Convention
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoverageenddate=2018-12-31T23:59:59
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoverageresolution=P1D
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoveragestartdate=2002-06-19T00:00:00
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Global long-term Vegetation optical depth climate-data aggregate VODCA
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"vodca_v01-0_C-band_2018-12-29.nc":vod
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[1x720x1440] vod (64-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"vodca_v01-0_C-band_2018-12-29.nc":sensor_flag
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[1x720x1440] sensor_flag (64-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:"vodca_v01-0_C-band_2018-12-29.nc":processing_flag
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[1x720x1440] processing_flag (64-bit floating-point)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

**Tif file after step 1**

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: vodca_v01-0_C-band_2018-12-30.tif
Size is 1440, 720
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)
Metadata:
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lat#valid_range={-90,90}
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  lon#valid_range={-180,180}
  NC_GLOBAL#_NCProperties=version=1|netcdflibversion=4.4.1.1|hdf5libversion=1.10.2
  NC_GLOBAL#band=C-band (6.8 GHz - 7.3 GHZ)
  NC_GLOBAL#calendar=standard
  NC_GLOBAL#contact=vodca@geo.tuwien.ac.at
  NC_GLOBAL#conventions=CF-1.6
  NC_GLOBAL#creatorname=Department of Geodesy and Geoinformation, Technical University of Vienna
  NC_GLOBAL#creatorurl=http://rs.geo.tuwien.ac.at
  NC_GLOBAL#DOI=10.5281/zenodo.2575599
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatmax=90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatmin=-90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatresolution=0.25 degree
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatunits=degrees_north
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonmax=180.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonmin=-180.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonresolution=0.25 degree
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonunits=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatialverticalmax=0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatialverticalmin=0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#insitute=Technical University of Vienna (AUT); Transmissivity B.V. / VanderSat B.V. Noordwijk (NL)
  NC_GLOBAL#license=Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International
  NC_GLOBAL#namingauthority=TU Wien
  NC_GLOBAL#product_version=01.0
  NC_GLOBAL#productname==VODCA
  NC_GLOBAL#sensors=SSMI, TMI, AMSR-E, WindSat, AMSR2
  NC_GLOBAL#spatialresolution=25 km
  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Convention
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoverageenddate=2018-12-31T23:59:59
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoverageresolution=P1D
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoveragestartdate=2002-06-19T00:00:00
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Global long-term Vegetation optical depth climate-data aggregate VODCA
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={1,6}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES=17895
  time#calendar=standard
  time#long_name=time
  time#units=days since 1970-1-1 0:0:0
  vod#_FillValue=-999999
  vod#long_name=Vegetation optical depth
  vod#units=unitless
  vod#valid_range={0,inf}
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) 
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) 
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Band 1 Block=1440x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-999999
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=-999999
    long_name=Vegetation optical depth
    NETCDF_DIM_time=17895
    NETCDF_VARNAME=vod
    units=unitless
    valid_range={0,inf}
```

**Final tif**

```
Size is 1483, 627
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Cylindrical_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-17367530.445161376148462,7342230.136498682200909)
Pixel Size = (23407.953829473473888,-23423.748670114142442)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lat#valid_range={-90,90}
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  lon#valid_range={-180,180}
  NC_GLOBAL#_NCProperties=version=1|netcdflibversion=4.4.1.1|hdf5libversion=1.10.2
  NC_GLOBAL#band=C-band (6.8 GHz - 7.3 GHZ)
  NC_GLOBAL#calendar=standard
  NC_GLOBAL#contact=vodca@geo.tuwien.ac.at
  NC_GLOBAL#conventions=CF-1.6
  NC_GLOBAL#creatorname=Department of Geodesy and Geoinformation, Technical University of Vienna
  NC_GLOBAL#creatorurl=http://rs.geo.tuwien.ac.at
  NC_GLOBAL#DOI=10.5281/zenodo.2575599
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatmax=90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatmin=-90.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatresolution=0.25 degree
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallatunits=degrees_north
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonmax=180.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonmin=-180.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonresolution=0.25 degree
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatiallonunits=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatialverticalmax=0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatialverticalmin=0.0
  NC_GLOBAL#insitute=Technical University of Vienna (AUT); Transmissivity B.V. / VanderSat B.V. Noordwijk (NL)
  NC_GLOBAL#license=Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International
  NC_GLOBAL#namingauthority=TU Wien
  NC_GLOBAL#product_version=01.0
  NC_GLOBAL#productname==VODCA
  NC_GLOBAL#sensors=SSMI, TMI, AMSR-E, WindSat, AMSR2
  NC_GLOBAL#spatialresolution=25 km
  NC_GLOBAL#standard_name_vocabulary=NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Convention
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoverageenddate=2018-12-31T23:59:59
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoverageresolution=P1D
  NC_GLOBAL#timecoveragestartdate=2002-06-19T00:00:00
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Global long-term Vegetation optical depth climate-data aggregate VODCA
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={1,6}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES=17894
  time#calendar=standard
  time#long_name=time
  time#units=days since 1970-1-1 0:0:0
  vod#_FillValue=-999999
  vod#long_name=Vegetation optical depth
  vod#units=unitless
  vod#valid_range={0,inf}
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-17367530.445, 7342230.136) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-17367530.445,-7344460.280) (180d 0' 0.00"W,-2147483648d-2147483648'  nan"N)
Upper Right (17346465.084, 7342230.136) (179d46'54.03"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (17346465.084,-7344460.280) (179d46'54.03"E,-2147483648d-2147483648'  nan"N)
Center      (  -10532.681,   -1115.072) (  0d 6'32.98"W,  0d 0'31.47"S)
Band 1 Block=1483x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=-999999
    long_name=Vegetation optical depth
    NETCDF_DIM_time=17894
    NETCDF_VARNAME=vod
    units=unitless
    valid_range={0,inf}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a few answers...

1. This is just a warning. Names of objects in netCDF are case sensitive, and `conventions` is ignored, thus it is assumed that the document does not use [CF Conventions and Metadata](http://cfconventions.org). The recognized global attribute to use is `Conventions` ([ref](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html#attribute-appendix)). You can use NCO's [ncrename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncrename) utility to rename the attribute:

   ```
   ncrename -a conventions,Conventions vodca_v01-0_C-band_2018-12-29.nc
   ```

   however, it may not solve any of the issues. Also, why are you using gdal_translate when you can just use gdalwarp?
2. The PROJ string in `-s_srs` has `+to`, which normally describes a conversion from one SRS to another. I suggest removing `+to wgs84=0,0,0`. As above, I suggest using the netCDF subdataset (`NETCDF:"$file":vod`) as the source input, then the same reprojected output GeoTIFF. Without seeing the output, the file looks fine according to `gdalinfo`. Does PIL work for float64 types. Try either rasterio or GDAL to read the raster data instead.